# IValidatableObject Validate Method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, ivalidatableobject

I have this class used in MVC3...

The Validation Attributes for each property are working as it should but when the Validate method is called and any results are returned it is not posting back to the form.
Can anyone help??

```
public class Register : IValidatableObject
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "District Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a District Name")]
    [StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "District Name must be between 1 and 40 characters")]
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Url Quick Find")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a Quick Find Name")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Url Quick Find must be between 3 and 15 characters")]
    public string QuickFind { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User name is requred")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Url Quick Find must be between 1 and 10 characters")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is requred")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Re-Enter Password")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must re-enter your password to confirm you have entered it correctly")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Display Name is requred")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Display Name must be between 1 and 20 characters")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email Address is requred")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Email Address must be between 4 and 50 characters")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Regex lettersOnly = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]*$");

        if (!lettersOnly.IsMatch(QuickFind))
            yield return new ValidationResult("Only letters A - Z are allowed in the Quick Find", new string[] { "QuickFind" });

        if (!lettersOnly.IsMatch(QuickFind))
            yield return new ValidationResult("Only letters A - Z are allowed for your User name", new string[] { "Username" });

        if (Password != PasswordConfirm)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Passwords do not match", new string[] { "Password", "PasswordConfirm" });

    }
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Register registration)
    {
        try
        {
            User newUser = RegistrationManager.Register(registration);
            RedirectToAction("Index", "District", newUser.ID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("There has been an Error during Registration", ex.Message);
            RedirectToAction("Details", "Error", ex);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

**View Code:**

```
@model PubGames.Data.Register
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
<h2>
    Register</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistrictName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistrictName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistrictName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuickFind)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuickFind)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuickFind)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: You need to also show us the relevant code in your controller, and view.

Comment: Added controller and view code

Comment: FYI, you don't really need `IValidatableObject` for the validations shown in your code sample; you can obtain the same results using data annotations alone: `[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters A - Z are allowed in {0}.")]` and `[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match.")]`. Data annotations also give you client-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many problems...

A typical Action method goes like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("somethign");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

This does several things, but primarily it returns the model state back to the view if it is not valid.  You are not doing that, and in fact you're not even return the model back to the view.  You're not checking if the state is valid, so it will try and call the register method even if validation fails serverside.  You're also not returning your ActionResults, ie RedirectToAction, you're just calling it..

Answer (score 1):

You are not redirecting correctly. You must **return** RedirectToAction:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Register registration)
{
    try
    {
        User newUser = RegistrationManager.Register(registration);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "District", newUser.ID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("There has been an Error during Registration", ex.Message);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Error", ex);
    }

    return View(registration);
}
```

Also when you redirect in the case of exception you will lose any errors that you have added to the modelstate.

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean "not posting back to the form" - you mean the errors on't show up? 
Ensure

1. You have a validation summary on the page
2. Are you NOT redirecting after your post.
3. be aware this isn't for client validation (just saying, you may already be aware)